# Why does the ToolBar Command "ToggleBold" has no function in an Regular TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, richtextbox

So Ive got an ToolBar and wanted to **Bold** my Text, with an **RichTextBox** its working but not with an normal regular TextBox. Could someone tell me why only RichTextBox is working and not the normal one? And how could I get the normal TextBox to work because the RichTextBox is impractical.

My Code looks like that:

```
<DockPanel>
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button Command="Cut" ToolTip="Cut selection to Windows Clipboard.">
                </Button>
                <Button Command="Copy" ToolTip="Copy selection to Windows Clipboard.">
                </Button>
                <Button Content="Hallo" Command="ToggleBold" ToolTip="Paste from Windows Clipboard.">
                   
                </Button>
                <Separator />
                <Label>Font size:</Label>
                <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBoxItem>10</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">12</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>14</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>16</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBox` does not support formatting related commands like `ToggleBold` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

| Control | Spellchecking | Context Menu | Formatting commands | FlowDocument content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TextBox | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| RichTextBox | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

See the documentation: [TextBox or RichTextBox?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#textbox-or-richtextbox)